# What does the +0+0 in geometry() mean in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry

I understand the very beginning which creates the window size, but I see people put +x+x after the initial 400x300 or whatever size. I've looked all over for an answer but can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`width x height + x position + y position`, positions relative to the top left corner of the screen in pixels

**Edit:**

[Here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.htm#M26)'s a brief summary of the function from tcl.tk, written up much more concisely than I could hope to achieve.

Comment: Simple and concise. I like it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

its just where do you want the pixel from, setting the top and left corner of the screen

you can also see the link http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm